# pkill does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pkill

I list all the processes in the system using `ps -aux`

and I found this java process:

```
10253  2.1 10.1 3259172 398864 pts/0  Tl   06:58   0:09 java -jar /opt/can-peris/core-price-update/menu-core-prices-update-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but when I try to kill it nothing happens

```
pkill -f /opt/can-peris/core-price-update/menu-core-prices-update-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and when I list again all the processes it appears again

Comment: pkill default sends a TERM signal only, not KILL.

Comment: The `T` status means it's stopped (suspended). You'll need to send a CONT signal after sending whatever signal you want. Or, as in your answer, a KILL signal will kill it even when it's stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works !

```
pkill -f -9 /opt/can-peris/core-price-update/menu-core-prices-update-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```